# Anti-swear filter for TCP server is glitching

Tags: javascript, server, tcp

I made an tcp server in js, and wanted to make an anti-swear filter.

I coded and tested it, but it is perfoming its operation twice: when anybody swears, they gets two warnings and then there are two warning messages in the chat.

Server Code (not the full code, only the part that is glitching) :

```js
//swear filter
let slist = fs.readFileSync("./swearinglist.txt")
let slist_array = slist.toString().split(",");
let sendable = true;


if (active) {
  slist_array.forEach((w) => {
    if (data.includes(w)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < clients; i++) {
        if (sockets[i] === socket) continue;
        sockets[i].write(socket.remotePort + " Sollte sich erstmal beruhigen !\n")
        mistakes = mistakes + 1;
        console.log(socket.remotePort + " Wollte  | " + data + " |  in den chat schrieben !");
        sendable = false
      };
    };
  });
}
```

I dont think that the client code matters, but here it is:

```
var net = require("net");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    prompt: "",
    terminal: false,
});

var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(8080, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    client.write(" Joined !")
});

client.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

client.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Connection closed');
    process.exit(); 
});

rl.prompt();
rl.on('line', (input) => {
    client.write(input)
    rl.prompt();
});
```

Comment: My guess that the reduced code is not sufficient to show the problem. It might simply be that the relevant code is called twice. Please make a [minimal, but actually reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show your problem instead of just showing the code snippets you deem relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it, it did the task for every conected socket. Fixed it !